# check to see if div is already showing, and hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am working on the responsive design of my website for mobile phones. I have an "img" tag inside of an "a" tag for 3 icons, like this:

```
  <a href="#"><img src="images/webIcon.png" data-attr="webIcon"></a>
```

On all other screen sizes, when a user hovers over the icon, a description appears, and then disappears again when they mouse-off. But on mobile phones, by the time they scroll down to view the description, it's gone, so I'm changing it to a click event on the "a" tag.
 I've successfully added the content where I want it when the user clicks on the appropriate icon, but I'm having trouble hiding it when the next icon is clicked, or if they click the same one again.
Here is what I have:

```
    $('#mobileServices a').hover(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //Grab the corresponding description for the icon
      data = $(this).children('img').attr('data-attr');
      section = $('#' + data + '').html();

      //Plop in the new section containing the description below the icon
      $(this).after('<section class=' + data + '>' + section + '</section');

      //So I figured perhaps I should store-off the new sections for later use
      newSection = $('section.' + data + '');
    });
```

So then I thought: I'll use a simple if statement to check if the newSection is visible, and if it is, hide it (or slide it up, or slideToggle it), but that logic isn't working. I'm getting into the if statement, because I checked it with console.log(s). I tried something like:

```
      if('section:visible') {
         newSection.slideToggle();
      }
```

But obviously that doesn't work, because it just slides it down and then up right away. So, now I'm stuck... Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!!

Comment: can you add a JSFiddle link that show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may lie with the `if` statement you're trying to use. You'll want to get the element(s) first, with `$('section')` and then do `.is(":visible");`. So, to tie it together:

```
// Checks for display:[none|block], ignores visible:[true|false]
if($('section').is(":visible")) {
    $('section').hide();
}
```

This will hide all the sections, and should achieve something close to what you're looking for. Then, you can show your new one with  `newSection.slideToggle()` and be good to go.